# How to save connection string in XML

Tags: vb.net

How to save connection string in XML so that I can subsequently use that string.  How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADONET FAQ - Storing and Retrieving Connection String in/from XML  ...

http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-ADONET-Store-Retrieve-Connection-String-XML-File